# haproxy ulimit-n computation

Tags: haproxy, ulimit

I got a [haproxy 1.8 vanilla alpine docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/haproxy/blob/feefabf1ea0f03879f9d529dcc5b8ec6f3112bba/1.8/alpine/Dockerfile) running with `maxconn = 2000`

```
curl -s http://host:port/stats| grep maxsock
<b>maxsock = </b> 4017; <b>maxconn = </b> 2000; <b>maxpipes = </b> 0<br>
```

Sometimes I get the following Warning in my logs:

```
[WARNING] 0/0 (0) : [/usr/local/sbin/haproxy.main()] FD limit (4015) too low for maxconn=2000/maxsock=4016. Please raise 'ulimit-n' to 4016 or more to avoid any trouble.
```

I find it very odd since I read this in [haproxy doc](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#ulimit-n):

> ulimit-n  
>   Sets the maximum number of per-process file-descriptors to . By
>   default, it is automatically computed, so it is recommended not to use this
>   option.

Not sure if it's a bug on haproxy or something I am doing wrong.

What do you think of that?

edit: `haproxy` is running as `root`

Comment: this might be a bug in haproxy: https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/how-does-ulimit-n-computation-works/2498

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the open file descriptor limit(hard and soft), you can check that by `ulimit -Hn` and `ulimit -Sn`.

It is automatically computed, but it depends on the user you run haproxy, if you run haproxy using `root` then even if the computed value is greater than hard limit, you can set that value without warning.

But if you run as a normal user, then the max value is hard limit, if the computed value is greater than that, you got the warning.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I am running it as `root`

Comment: both hard and soft limits are at `1048576`

Comment: this might be a bug in haproxy: https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/how-does-ulimit-n-computation-works/2498

Comment: @vinni_f you run haproxy directly from command line? or through systemd?

Comment: I use the [master worker mode](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#3.1-master-worker)